# Presto filter array of rows inside aggregation

Tags: sql, presto

I have a set of impressions (banners) which could have been or not clicked. I want to count the appearances of ips but only for those impressions that were clicked.

```
WITH imps AS (
  SELECT
    day,
    source_id,
    ip,
    trans_id
  FROM
    xxx
),
clicks AS (
  SELECT 
    day,
    trans_id,
    1 AS clicked,
  FROM
    yyy
)

SELECT
  imps.source_id as source_id,
  histogram(
    filter(zip(array_agg(ip), array_agg(clicked)), x -> x.clicked = 1)
  ) as ip_hist
FROM
  imps
LEFT JOIN
  clicks
    ON imps.trans_id = clicks.trans_id
GROUP BY
  imps.source_id;
```

This is the query I tried, and it didn't work as clicked is not a column. It's not clear to me if this can even be done on Presto. Also, this is part of a way more complex query and that's why i want to do the filter inside the aggregation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use the filtered aggregation syntax [`agg_function(...) filter (where expression)`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#filtering-during-aggregation), which applies a filter immediately before adding the value to the specific function.  Additionally, you can eliminate the join in the query by using an `in` clause with a subquery.

I believe this is what you want:

```
WITH
 imps(source_id, ip, trans_id) AS (
     VALUES
         (1, 1, 1),
         (2, 2, 2),
         (3, 3, 3)
),
clicks(trans_id) AS (
    VALUES 1, 3
)
SELECT source_id,
    histogram(ip) filter (where trans_id in (select trans_id from clicks))
FROM imps
GROUP BY source_id
```